# How to Blob Javascript (Binary Large Object) read file from disk on *nux?

Tags: javascript, unix, ecmascript-6

How to Blob Javascript (Binary Large Object) attach file from disk in Ubuntu?

```
let blob = new Blob(['Hello, world!'], {type: 'text/plain'});
```

but i need to add file csv from /home/user/test.csv or from [www.a.com/test.csv](http://www.a.com/test.csv)

The main problem is I need to upload self-created csv file to website field

Solution:
PHP code on server generate Csv.
I need to attach from /home/user/website/export/export.csv or i can put on website-> [www.website.com/export.csv](http://www.website.com/export.csv)

After i emulate Chrome 87 with JS support

```
$client = Client::createChromeClient();,
```

go to webpage where i need to upload csv (another web not my)
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.anotherWeb.com/ProductsImportFileList.aspx?');

Log In

```
$crawler->filter('#ctl00_uxAuthenticationBlock_uxLoginText')->sendKeys($username[$userIndex]);
            $loggerAwareTrait->notice('Type username');
            sleep(1);
            $crawler->filter('#ctl00_uxAuthenticationBlock_uxPasswordText')->sendKeys($uassword[$userIndex]);
            sleep(1);
            $loggerAwareTrait->notice('Type password');
```

$jsLoginStepOneLink = "document.querySelector('#ctl00_uxAuthenticationBlock_uxLoginFirstButton').click()";
$client->executeScript($jsLoginStepOneLink);

I found one solution how i can upload blob to

```
function pasteBlobToInput(blob, input) {
```

var file = new File([blob], blob.name);

var file_list = {0: file, length: 1, '**proto**': input['files']['**proto**']};

var proto = input['**proto**'];

input['**proto**'] = document.createElement('div')['**proto**'];

input['files'] = file_list;

input['**proto**'] = proto;

console.log('Collection inserted:');
console.dir(file_list);

input.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('change', { bubbles: true }));

}

Comment: How/where are you executing the code?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Could you please clarify it?